# Tailwind css - use className custom spacing value as variable for tailwind config

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

Is there a way to pass custom value for spacing (or other parameters) to tailwind config schema instead of prescribing all the values i need in tailwind config?

For example, when using custom spacing values in px for HTML element like this:

`<div className="mt-15px pb-36px h-500px></div>`

I currently use next tailwind config:

```
    ...
    spacing: {
            "15px": "15px",
            "36px": "36px",
    },
    height: {
            "500px": "500px"
        }
    ...
```

Instead i'd like to have something like this if it is possible:

```
 ...
    spacing: {
            "${var}px": "${var}px",
    },
    height: {
            "${var}px": "${var}px"
        }
    ...
```

Basically to pass any number to tailwind styles for spacing or other similar parameters without the necessity to prescribe it into config.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy with new **JIT** mode, using feature called arbitrary value.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#arbitrary-value-support

```
<img class="absolute w-[762px] h-[918px] top-[-325px] right-[62px] md:top-[-400px] md:right-[80px]" src="/crazy-background-image.png">
```

No need to predefine this in config. You can stick with standard spacing based on Rem, and use arbitrary values only for special cases (for ex. when pixel perfect is needed).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's just what i've needed!